# Count characters in textarea onload

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm trying to create a simple tool to count the length of a title/meta description. I managed to create the character counter (without jQuery). However, upon page load there is a default text entered in each textarea and I would like it to be included in the count.

The length of this default text might change (people will be able to import their own title/meta description from a URL so I can't use a fixed length in the code).

Is there a way to count the content of the textarea using "document.onload"? I found various topics discussing it but since I'm a super-beginner in JS, I haven't managed to adapt the code to my own situation :-/

Thanks if you can help!

Preview on Codepen : https://codepen.io/pen/OzagNQ

Here is the HTML part:

```
<label for="titletag">Title</label><br>
<div class="wrap">
<textarea name="text" id="titletag" cols="100" rows="1" oninput="count_title('titletag','ctitle')">Default title (variable length).</textarea><span id="ctitle" class="counter"></span></div><br><br>

<label for="metadesc">Meta description</label><br>
<div class="wrap">
<textarea name="metadesc" cols="100" rows="5" oninput="count_mdesc()" id="metadesc">Default meta description (variable length).</textarea><span id="cmdesc" class="counter"></span></div>
```

And the JS part:

```
window.load = function() {
   count_title(document.getElementById('titletag'), document.getElementById('ctitle'));
 }

 function count_title() {
   var el_t = document.getElementById('titletag');
   var length = 70;
   var el_c = document.getElementById('ctitle');
   el_c.innerHTML = length;
   el_t.oninput = function() {
     document.getElementById('ctitle').innerHTML = (length - this.value.length);
   };
 }

 function count_mdesc() {
   var el_t = document.getElementById('metadesc');
   var length = 320;
   var el_c = document.getElementById('cmdesc');
   el_c.innerHTML = length;
   el_t.oninput = function() {
     document.getElementById('cmdesc').innerHTML = (length - this.value.length);
   };
 }

 function pageRefresh() {
   count_title();
   count_mdesc();
 }

 window.onload = function() {
   pageRefresh();
 }
```

Comment: There is no `window.load`, there is `window.onload` which you define correctly at the bottom, unless you really want a `load()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **el_t.value.length** to get the length of each element outside of your oninput function:

```
function count_title() {
  var el_t = document.getElementById("titletag");
  var maxLength = 70;
  var el_c = document.getElementById("ctitle");
  el_c.innerHTML = maxLength - el_t.value.length;
  el_t.oninput = function() {
    document.getElementById("ctitle").innerHTML = maxLength - this.value.length;
  };
}
function count_mdesc() {
  var el_t = document.getElementById("metadesc");
  var maxLength = 320;
  var el_c = document.getElementById("cmdesc");
  el_c.innerHTML = maxLength - el_t.value.length;
  el_t.oninput = function() {
    document.getElementById("cmdesc").innerHTML = maxLength - this.value.length;
  };
}
function pageRefresh() {
  count_title();
  count_mdesc();
}

window.onload = function() {
  pageRefresh();
};
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZreOx

You might also want to consider refactoring these two functions into a single function to make your code a bit more maintainable:

```
function count_element(tag, ctag, maxLength) {
  var el_t = document.getElementById(tag);
  var el_c = document.getElementById(ctag);
  el_c.innerHTML = maxLength - el_t.value.length;
  el_t.oninput = function() {
    document.getElementById(ctag).innerHTML = maxLength - this.value.length;
  };
}

function pageRefresh() {
  count_element("titletag", "ctitle", 70);
  count_element("metadesc", "cmdesc", 320);
}

window.onload = function() {
  pageRefresh();
};
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJQqjg